# Randomization of treatments in R studio

Tags: random, statistics, rstudio, anova

I want to get a randomization of treatments with three levels and sample size n = 15. I'm stuck in where

volunteers <- 1:15
set.seed(1); sample(volunteers, size=5, replace=F)

I want three different groups, five each, but I'm new to R.

This is a data setup for ANOVA, not a specific question which gives particular data sets. Also I don't know what it means for set.seed

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like that:

```
set.seed(1337)
# replace with you real participants ids
volunteers <- 1:15
# set the number of groups
number.of.groups <- 1:3
# set group size
group.size <- 5
# generate data frame with participant > group order
df <- data.frame(group=sort(rep(number.of.groups,group.size)),
                 participant=sample(volunteers,length(volunteers)))

# show your groups
df[which(df$group==1),]
# group participant
# 1     1           9
# 2     1           8
# 3     1           1
# 4     1           6
# 5     1           5
df[which(df$group==2),]
# group participant
# 6      2           4
# 7      2          15
# 8      2           3
# 9      2           2
# 10     2          13
df[which(df$group==3),]
# group participant
# 11     3          11
# 12     3          10
# 13     3          14
# 14     3          12
# 15     3           7
```

And you only need to use set.seed() if want to be able to replicate your samples since this method causes that you always draw the same "random" samples. Consequently, set.seed() is more for testing than for real analysis code. The seed you set is by the way irrelevant. If you want to replicate just make sure to always set the same seed.

Comment: @yoon if this answer helped, please consider selecting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark. This lets community know the answer worked and the issue is closed.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
install.packages("randomizr")
library(randomizr)
Z <- complete_ra(15, num_arms = 3)
table(Z)
```

This gives

```
> table(Z)
Z
T1 T2 T3 
 5  5  5
```